# Firebase auth failed using google signin

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

App was running quite fine a while ago all on a sudden it started showing this exception-

> PlatformException(sign_in_failed,
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null)

Already checked and updated sha-1 and google-service.json

```dart
 GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      await _auth
          .signInWithGoogle(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      )
          .then(
            (user) => _signInSuccessful(user),
      )
          .catchError(
            (e) {
          print(e);
        },
      );
```

Comment: did you upload your app in playstore ?

Comment: All of a sudden I am having the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: In my case it was because I was trying to log in without being connected to the internet. Finally, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Basically problem is in the SHA1 key put on console please regenerate it and put again properly same project.

1)As the answers, make sure that your actual signed Android apk has the same SHA1 fingerprint as what you specified in the console of your Firebase project's Android integration section (the page where you can download the google-services.json)

2)On top of that go to the Settings of your firebase project (gear icon right to the Overview at the top-left area. Then switch to Account Linking tab. On that tab link the Google Play to your project.

I was facing the same issue, After checking around for a solution, from regenerating the finger print to linking the app on firebase to the Google play console and publishing the signed apk, the issue was actually because I was using the release SHA-1 on the firebase console.

If you are still on debut mode, use the debug.keystore SHA1
Only use the release SHA1 if you are on production mode
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an app that was working fine (Google Play Store sign-in with firebase). A few days ago (maybe after the update of Android Studio to 3.3) the sign-in wasn’t working. After many other tries I reconnected the app with firebase and everything was fine.
If I now press Tools-Firebase-Analytics-Log an Analytics event (in Android studio), I can see point 1 and 2 is green. That wasn’t before.
After the reconnection the *.json-file was changed. But I think, it won’t work with the *.json-file from firebase.
Maybe it’s worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Also had this issue, but for me the best solution is adding both the debug and release Certificate SHA-1 fingerprints to the Firebase console (who knew you could add both), then downloading the new google-services.json file into the project.

Now I can successfully login within the app for debug and release builds.